# Angular highcharts treemap squarified fit tiles

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to display a treemap squarified chart using this library. The problem is when 1 of the categories has a value greater than the others, but with a high value respect the others.

As you can see in this jsfiddle whe you have one member with 6000 as value and the others with 6 you can only see 1 member

**Edited:** I cold finally see the other squares. Now the question is: how can I make those small squares bigger than how they are now?

Because the people who will use this chart won't distinguish the text. Well, I couldn't see it so that's why I made this post.

https://jsfiddle.net/unx1Larf/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: "treemap",
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'A',
            value: 6000
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            value: 6
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            value: 4
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            value: 3
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: 'G',
            value: 1
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually can see them. they are just like 1px wide, given the proportion, that's probably relatively accurate.

Comment: If you change the 6000 data value to 6 you'll see it does work

Comment: Imagine you are a person from human resources department. You want to see this chart but you can't distinguish what is written. 

I'll edit the question. The question is, how can I make those small squares bigger than how they are now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them bigger by setting smaller value for the big square and make tooltip display the real value. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      realValue: 6000,
      value: 100
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      value: 6
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      value: 4
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      value: 3
    }, {
      name: 'E',
      value: 2
    }, {
      name: 'F',
      value: 2
    }, {
      name: 'G',
      value: 1
    }]
  }],
  tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
     return this.point.realValue || this.point.value;
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wgevrz4m/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: I changed current "value" property to "realValue" and add "value" property with default value and now every square fits perfect.